# How do I use variables from another PHP include file in a function?

Tags: php, variables, scope, global

I have this PHP include file that has all the variables I'll be using. How can I use all those variables in another file in a function, without declaring them again as global in that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access all variables of the global scope with:

```
$GLOBALS['varname']
```

To avoid the use of the $GLOBALS all the time you can "globalize" variables automatically:

Place this in your function to "import" all variables:

```
foreach($GLOBALS as $key=>$val){
    if(!isSuperGlobal($key))
        global $$key;
}
```

And put this help function somewhere else outside your function

```
function isSuperGlobal($name){
    switch($name){
        case 'GLOBALS':
        case '_SERVER':
        case '_GET':
        case '_POST':
        case '_FILES':
        case '_COOKIE':
        case '_SESSION':
        case '_REQUEST':
        case '_ENV':        return true;    break;
        default:            return false;   break;
    }
}
```

Comment: so if the variable name is "somevariable" and is in another include file, i can do this for the function calling it: $GLOBALS['somevariable'];

Comment: Tricky :) Great idea, very simple.

Comment: Sorry, I think this is a terrible idea.  There could be dozens or hundreds of these variables and you may only want to use one or two.  I would recommend Craig's method.  I use it extensively.

Answer (score 5):

A function cannot access outside variables without either including them or declaring them as global or getting them from globals. In the past I have created both an array and easy to read variables. I then reference the array variable and have to reach the variable by name.

Comment: I like this (or the object suggestion below) as it avoids polluting the Global namespace with lots of variables.

Answer (score 2):

You *should* pass them to the function as arguments. If there are to many to do this consider using objects instead of just functions, then instantiate instances of the object in your main file. Or as Craig mentions, pass the global variables in an options array in addition to your primary function arguments.